# How to reset the root password of the Ubuntu system on Live CD?

Tags: password, root, live-cd

Recently I got a customized Live CD image of Ubuntu 18.04.3 to install a customized Ubuntu system on a Hyper-V virtual machine on my Windows computer.

However, I have only obtained the password of a limited (without `sudo` access) user of the system on Live CD. I do not know the password of the root user either. Is there a way to reset the password of root of the system on Live CD?

On the Internet I have found several tutorials to reset the root password of the **host machine** using Live CD, but I have not found any document for resetting the root password of Live CD itself. Is it possible to extract files from the CD image, modify files like `/etc/shadow` and pack the modified files up?

I am currently working on Windows, and can access several computers running Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04, so tools on Windows and Linux can both be used. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it's a customized live CD, then you'll have to ask it's creator. The standard Ubuntu ISOs do not have a root user, only a default *live* user which has `sudo` rights. Root user is disabled by default.

Comment: @guiverc It is still possible to unsquash the original squashfile, chroot it, and create a dummy password for user root. I think it should also be possible in OP's situation as well, yet they'll have to repack the squash and create a new live cd.

Comment: "Is it possible to extract files from the CD image, modify files like `/etc/shadow` and pack the modified files up?" -- Yes, but quite complicated. It is better to ask the creator of the customized CD image.

Comment: I actually customized a live ubuntu 18.04 squash some time ago, adding it an ssh-server and creating a root password (just for ssh connections). This also gives absolute root access to everything in the system.

Comment: @Pizza, That's great :-) You are welcome to write an answer with enough details to be useful for the original poster, and I will upvote it (if you ping me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you can change every squash (aka live) system. There some tools available. All have in common that you need a running Linux System, an ISO Image (e.g a downloaded Ubuntu20.04.iso) and some spare memory/space.

This is the only way to alter the contents of an ISO, since it mimics a CD or DVD which is not writable.

If you want to take this path you could look up the [Ubuntu LiveCDCustomization](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization) (this works) or check the [article for a GUI driven solution](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/07/how-to-customize-ubuntu-or-linux-mint.html).

In each case the ISO needs to be unpacked/copied, its contents altered and put back into an ISO file which you could use.